# Angular ng-repeat refresh from WebApi2 response.data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created an angular function where a get data from from a WebApi. 
This function get data in json format with an $http.get call.

Then I receive data from into response.data object.

```
    dataService.GetDataFromApi.then(
         function(response){
             ctrl.items = response.data; },
    function(error){});
```

In html view page I use ng-repeat to show all item from response.data.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in ControllerNama.items">
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This work fine.

Now, I need to refresh view page after click a button into html. When I click this button, one of items are removed from another api. I can call same api and refresh data (with overhead) or I can remove data from ctrl.items without call refresh-api (if remove api return 200 status code).

Which are the best soluzion? How I can refresh repeat object by controller without call GetDataFromApi function?

Thanks?

Comment: Try use `$scope.$evalAsync(function(){  ctrl.items = response.data;})`

Comment: **I need to refresh view page after click a button into html** what do you mean by this?

Comment: You can just slice the deleted data from ctrl.items or call the get call on the success of deletion.

Comment: When I click button in view a call an api that remove item from db. Then if I receive a 200 status code, I think to delete item from ctrl.items, without re-call api that get all items (with overhead). Than I think... remove the element from ctrl.items and the view is updated. If this is not correct solution, I can call directly the get-all api. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having too much information on how you're populating the collection being iterated on in `ng-repeat`, I can provide how I typically handle binding to collections retrieved from an API call.

Typically, I'll set up an Angular service that contains a function for the API call, as well as an object with a property that represents the array. For instance:

```
(function () {
    var apiSvc = function ($q, $http) {
        var
            model = function () {
                collection = [];

                return {
                    collection: collection
                };
            },
            getCollection = function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http({
                    url: '/api/something/getCollection',
                    method: 'GET'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    model.collection = data;
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (err) {
                    // Do something if this fails
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            };

        return {
            model: model,
            getCollection: getCollection
        };
    };

    // Inject external angular modules into the service
    apiSvc.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

    // Add the service to your angular module
    apiApp.factory('appSvc', appSvc);
}());
```

Then, as an example using a directive, you would inject the service into the directive and bind the model object to a scope object on the directive:

```
(function () {
    var apiDirective = function (apiSvc) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/content/templates/demo-directive.html',
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.model = demoSvc.model;
                apiSvc.getCollection();
            }
        }
    };

    apiDirective.$inject = ['apiSvc'];
    apiApp.directive('apiDirective', apiDirective);
}());
```

And iterate through the collection in the template as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in model.collection track by $index">
    <p ng-bind="item.property"></p>
</div>
```

Then, if you do anything that would modify the collection, simply call the service function to update the collection, and your view should reflect the updates.

Comment: Thanks! What I need to do is remove an item from database (calling an api). If status code is 200, I don't want re-call api to get all element from database, but I think to remove it from local collection and automatically refresh view (in ng-repeat loop). Thanks

Comment: If you're working with a REST API, your view should always be in sync with the API itself. If you execute a delete, it should be done through the API, and the collection should then be updated through the API. This is why the data-bound object is defined in the service. The view doesn't 'refresh', it just adapts to changes to the data bindings as a result of interactions with the service.

Comment: Ok. Then I delete record using api and refresh by api. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! If this satisfies your question, please mark as answer :)